# animate() function not work properly in EXTJS4 with IE 8

Tags: extjs, internet-explorer-8, extjs4, jquery-animate

I am using EXTJS 4 with IE 8 for my project. I created a one animation for sequence of small circles. At one interval of 1 second one circle disappeared and other circle disappeared.

Code :-

```
me.startAnimation=function(circles,color,direction,startIndex,initIndex)
       { 
           try
           {
               circles.items[startIndex].animate({
                duration: 0,
                to: {      
                    fill:'#fff'
                }              

            }).animate({
                delay: 1000,                    
                to: {    

                    fill:color
                },
                listeners: {

                    afteranimate: function() {

                        // Execute my custom method after the animation

                        if(direction==='direct')
                            startIndex++;
                        else
                            startIndex--;
                        if(startIndex===circles.length || startIndex<0)                       
                            startIndex=initIndex;      
                        this.startAnimation(circles,color,direction,startIndex,initIndex);
                    },
                    scope: this
                }
            });
        }
        catch(e)
        {                
            return;
        }

    }
```

[image]
So this animation is worked fine in Chrome and Firefox but in IE 8 Created a problem. IN IE 8 circle is not disappeared completely as show in above image. So, where is the problem out of three (IE 8, EXTJS 4, ANIMATE FUNCTIOn)...?

Comment: I don't know what's the problem with IE8 but i just increase circle radius to 3 to 3.2 and now it seems to work fine like chrome and Firefox... maybe IE8 GUI engine's pixel value is slite different as compare to chrome and Firefox